# What does the multiplication operator do in this code?

Tags: javascript

So I saw this code and have no clue what the `*` in `sortBy[i].direction*(...)` does. Can anyone break this down for me and help me understand this code?

```js
result = sortBy[i].direction*(a[ sortBy[i].prop ] < b[ sortBy[i].prop ] ? -1 : (a[ sortBy[i].prop ] > b[ sortBy[i].prop ] ? 1 : 0));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `*` operator multiples the value of `sortBy[i].direction` with

- -1 if `a[sortBy[i].prop] < b[sortBy[i].prop]`;
- 1 if `a[sortBy[i].prop] > b[sortBy[i].prop]`;
- 0 otherwise.

Look at this as

```
result = sortBy[i].direction * 
  (a[sortBy[i].prop] < b[sortBy[i].prop] 
    ? -1
    : (a[sortBy[i].prop] > b[sortBy[i].prop] 
      ? 1
      : 0));
```